# Insert data into database from inside controller method

Tags: laravel, twilio-php

I am new to programming and I am just learning. I am using Laravel and Twilio to make an SMS based evaluation app. At this point my app will send a question to a recipient and the recipient can respond. This part is functional. However, I need to be able to store the recipient's response in my data base. It is important for me to differ "Yes" responses from "No" responses. I am unsure on how to insert this data into the database in this situation.

I have tried to use an if statement to do this. For example, if answer is yes, upload "yes" data to the database. If answer is no, upload "no" data to the database. I have tried to create code that does this type of logic. Below is my attempt only at inserting data following a "yes" response.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\Jwt\ClientToken;
use Twilio\Twiml;
use App\res_eval_datasets;
use Session;
use DB;


class AskFirstQuestionsController extends Controller
{
public function qOneResponse(Request $request) {

    $responderNumber = $request->input('From');
    session()->put('responderNumber', $responderNumber);
    $responderAnswer = strtolower($request->input('Body'));

    if (strpos($responderAnswer, 'yes') !== false) {
        $attending_name =  session::get('attending_name');
        $resident_name =  session::get('residentName');
        $firstQuestion =  session::get('first_question'); 
        DB::table('res_eval_datasets')- 
        >insert(['attending'=>$attending_name,'resident_name'=>
        $resident_name,'question_id' =>$firstQuestion, 'answer_yes'=>1]);
        $smsResponse = "Thank You for teaching!";

    } else if (strpos($responderAnswer, 'no') !== false) {
        $smsResponse = "Ugh, ok...we will work on this";

    } else if (strpos($responderAnswer, 'ids') !== false) {
        $smsResponse = "Let's try a different question";

    } else {
        $smsResponse = "Please answer yes, no or dns.";
    }

    return response($this->respond($smsResponse))->header('Content-Type', 
    'application/xml');
}

public function respond($smsResponse) {
    $response = new Twiml();
    $response->message($smsResponse, ['to' => '+15303219327']);
    //session()->flush();
    session()->forget('firstQuestionSent');

    return $response;
}
```

This keeps giving me a 500 internal server error when I attempt this. I have a feeling my problem is with the database connection.

Comment: Take a look at Laravel's [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)  Models, these will make sure you almost never have to worry about query. With Eloquent this could be as simple as: `SmsReponse::create(["attending"=>...])` to store SmsReponses. This will also allow you to build object oriented models around your response table.

Comment: Another hint is to make sure your app is not in production mode so you can inspect the full error instead of just getting a 500 error splash screen. You should see something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PZ40.png

Comment: Thank you so much. That seemed to work, but it uncovered a different problem...I am unable to access my session variables which is why they were not being loaded into the database. I can not figure out how to solve this. I think it might be time for a new question.

Comment: Yes, I use Laravel as a REST API, I know nothing about session.